# ¿Puedo usar $_SESSION dentro de un método de PHP?

Tags: php, http-get, matrices-asociativas

Muy buenas.

Se supone que estoy intentando hacer un carrito de la compra con PHP y orientado a objetos. De forma estructurada, yo lo haría tal que así:

```html
 if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
                    $codigo=$_GET['id'];
                    if (!isset($_SESSION['carrito'][$codigo])){
                    $_SESSION['carrito'][$codigo]=1;
                    }else{
                    $_SESSION['carrito'][$codigo]++;
                     
                    }
```

Donde $codigo sería la variable mediante el cual accedo al array asociativo y listo la cantidad de productos que hay.

Ahora, mi duda es si yo podría meter ese mismo código dentro de un método que sea, por ejemplo, nuevoItem y paserle un código mediante parámetros.

Un saludo y gracias por ayudar a este novato.

Answer (score 0):

Por supuesto, puedes usar variables globales de sesión dentro de un método. Todo esto funcionará siempre y cuando tengas activada las sesiones, o en todo caso, reanudar las existentes.

```
session_start();
```

Un método sencillo podría ser el siguiente:

```
public function MiMetodo($id){
    @session_start();
    if (isset($id)){ 
        $codigo = $id;

        if (!isset($_SESSION['carrito'][$codigo])){
            $_SESSION['carrito'][$codigo] = 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['carrito'][$codigo]++;
        }
    } 
}
```

Llamada del método:

```
$this->MiMetodo($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!